# Show/hide multiple forms depending on dropdown without conditional statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I need to show/hide three forms depending on dropdown selected option without using conditional statements. Is it possible?

Comment: `without using conditional statements`? Why can't you use them? I would say no, you can't have a condition without a conditional.

Comment: Please provide some code and more explanation. You did tag `jQuery`. We cannot understand the question bound.

Comment: @user3783243 i have different forms for different types of products and I need to change them dynamically depending on dropdown selected option without using conditional statements...

Comment: @TalRofe I didn't start to code yet it's just three forms that are changing depending on the selected option. It's easy with conditional statements to check which option is selected, but documentation does not allow conditional statements.

Comment: @КристијанИсајлоски Then you can apply event listener to the select and trigger visibility of the form pressed.

Comment: *"documentation does not allow conditional statements"*. What documentation are you referring to? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so, please reference with:
https://api.jquery.com/on/

The idea is to apply event listener for each select option.

```js
const $selectElement = $('#select');

$selectElement.on('change', () => {
  $('form').css('display', 'none');
  $(`[data-id="${$selectElement.val()}"]`).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<form data-id="1">
  <span>1</span>
</form>

<form data-id="2">
  <span>2</span>
</form>

<form data-id="3">
  <span>3</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.   I would just use a **Map** and do something like this (UNTESTED!):

```js
const myDropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");

const resetVisibilityOfForms = () => Object.keys(formMap).forEach(form => document.querySelector(form).style.visibility = 'hidden');

const formMap = {
    'default': () => resetVisibilityOfForms(),
    'formId1': () => resetVisibilityOfForms() && document.querySelector('myForm1').style.visibility = 'visible',
    'formId2': () => resetVisibilityOfForms() && document.querySelector('myForm2').style.visibility = 'visible'
};

myDropdown.onchange = (e) => {
  const selectedForm = myDropdown.options[myDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

  formMap[selectedForm]();
};

// just hide all the forms by default...
resetVisibilityOfForms();
```

This would work with HTML like the following:

```html
<form id="formId1">....</form>
<form id="formId2">....</form>

<select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="default">Choose a form</option>
    <option value="formId1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="formId2">Form 2</option>
</select>
```

There are *many* ways to improve the above code too.  You could simplify the map, create a different type of map, use an array or any number of other different approaches.  Point isn't to create a production ready example to the above though - just to create an example to give you some ideas of how to go about it.

Good luck!

Comment: A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a specialized object in javascript. Code shown has nothing to with a global Map object

Comment: @charlietfl yes I'm quite aware of the built-in Map object.   that's yet another way to go about doing the same thing.  But what I've built above is a map as well...

Comment: hashmap perhaps but not a capital *"M"* Map that most would consider to be the built in Map object